# How to transfer data from one webpage to another?

Tags: jsoup

I'm using Android Studio.

In `Jsoup.connect("some url").data("String key,String value").post()`, what do the parameters in data() method mean?

I basically want to create a front-end login page of my own that will take the name and password of a student in textfields and on clicking some command button on the front-end page, the name and password will be sent at the BACK END to the name and password fields of my college's login page, which will ultimately access the college's database. So I want to send data from my login page to the college's login page(at the back end).

In this context, what would the parameters in `data()` method mean?

Comment: read about data() in the docs: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#data-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> **Connection data(String key, String value)**
>   Add a request data parameter. Request parameters are sent in the request query string for GETs, and in the request body for POSTs. A request may have multiple values of the same name.

References:
[`data` method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#data-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)